Contradictory unprovable statements in Tarski's "The Concept of Truth in Formalized Languages"
In Tarski's "The Concept of Truth in Formalized Languages", he glosses over the proof of a difficult lemma. I am looking for help writing a proof of it. In Tarski's notation, it is:



In modern notation this would be

Lemma E: Both (∀x)(∀y)(x⊂y)∉Pr and ¬[(∀x)(∀y)(x⊂y)]∉Pr

with ⊂ being inclusion and Pr the set of provable sentences. The footnote claims

The idea of the proof of both of these lemmas is the same as that of the
proofs of the consistency and incompleteness of the lower functional calculus

but I do not understand how Lemma E follows. A proof can either follow Tarski's notation or be a modern proof. The definition of Pr in "The Concept..." is that it is the set of sentences that are consequences of axioms. The definition of consequences and axioms are rather long but I can supply them if needed.

IMO the first formula has ⊆; if so - assuming usual axiom for sets - it amounts to saying that there is only one set. Thus, in usual set theory, the formula must be unprovable.

But, at an intuitive level, it seems symply an expression of GIT: under suitable condiitons, IF the calculus of classes is consistent, then there is a sentence G of the theory that is undecidable, i.e. such that neither G nor ¬G are provable (they do not belong to the collection Pr of provable sentences).

I think I solved the Lemma. The footnote implies that a system is consistent if the axioms and rules of inference are satisfied for a given model. By evaluating disjunction as the logical product, inclusion as the logical consequence, and quantification as the transformations (x)F(x) to F(1)&F(2) and (∃x)F(x) to F(1)∨F(~1) with 1 and 2 as specific variables, I was able to show all axioms and theorems constructed by rules of inferences were satisfied with the model. I showed both formulas of Lemma E were not. By induction on the complexity of Pr, they aren't provable.
